Solving $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec x}+\sqrt{\csc x}}dx$
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec x}+\sqrt{\csc x}}dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec x}+\sqrt{\csc x}}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+t^{2}}{1-t^{2}}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}}}\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}dt\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}2t}{\left(t^{2}+1\right)\left(t^{2}+2t-1\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{2t}\left(1-t^{2}\right)}{\left(t^{2}+1\right)\left(t^{2}+2t-1\right)}\right)dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}{t^{2}+1}+\frac{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}{t^{2}+2t-1}+\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{t^{2}+1}-\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{t^{2}+2t-1}\right)dt\\
&\qquad -2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}\frac{t}{t^{2}+1}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}+1\right)\sqrt{\cos x}dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\cos x}\tan\frac{x}{2}dx\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\cos x-\sin x}\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}\right)dx\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(2-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-2\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\cos x-\sin x}\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}\right)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}-1-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+1}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}\left(1-\tan x\right)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}-1-\frac{1}{2}I_0
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
I_0&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+1}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}\left(1-\tan x\right)}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\cos x}\sin\left(x\right)\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+1}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}dx\\
&\qquad +\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\cos x}\cos\left(x\right)\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+1}+1-\sqrt{2\sin2x}}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{\cos x+1}dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\cos x}{\cos x+1}dx \\
&\qquad +\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}\cos x}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}\sin x}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}dx\\
&\qquad -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}\cos x}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}\sqrt{2\sin2x}dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}\sin x}{\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x}\sqrt{2\sin2x}dx
\end{align*}$$
I got stuck here

Another algebraic form: $2 \int_0^\infty \frac{u^2 ,du}{(1 + u^4)^{5/4} (1 + u)}$.

The integral can be shown equal to $4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+(x^{-4}-1)^{1/4})^2}$, yet still almost impossible to have a decent representation.

Mathematica produces $$\frac{1}{\pi ^3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)},,G_{5,5}^{5,5}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4} \
0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4} \
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Recall Equation $(3.681\,\text{-}\,1)$ from Book Table of Integrals, Series, and Products by I.S. Gradshtein and I.M. Ryzhik, Page $(411)$:


Simplify the Integral:
$$ 
\begin{align} I 
&= \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec{x}}+\sqrt{\csc{x}}} \,dx \\[1mm] 
&= \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}\,\cos{x}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}+\sqrt{\cos{x}}} \,dx \\[1mm] 
&= \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}\,\cos{x}} \left(\sqrt{\sin{x}}-\sqrt{\cos{x}}\right)}{\sin{x}-\cos{x}} \,dx \\[1mm] 
&= \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}\,\cos{x}} \left(\sqrt{\cos{x}}-\sqrt{\sin{x}}\right)\left(\sin{x}+\cos{x}\right)}{\cos(2x)} \,dx \\[3mm] 
&= \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}}\left[\, \frac{\sin^{2{\color{red}{\frac54}}-1}{x}\,\cos^{2{\color{red}{\frac44}}-1}{x}}{\left(1-{\color{blue}{2}}\sin^2{x}\right)^{\color{blue}{1}}}-\frac{\sin^{2{\color{red}{\frac44}}-1}{x}\,\cos^{2{\color{red}{\frac54}}-1}{x}}{\left(1-{\color{blue}{2}}\sin^2{x}\right)^{\color{blue}{1}}} \,\right]dx \\[1mm] 
&+ \int\limits_{0}^{{\pi}/{2}}\left[\, \frac{\sin^{2{\color{red}{\frac34}}-1}{x}\,\cos^{2{\color{red}{\frac64}}-1}{x}}{\left(1-{\color{blue}{2}}\sin^2{x}\right)^{\color{blue}{1}}}-\frac{\sin^{2{\color{red}{\frac64}}-1}{x}\,\cos^{2{\color{red}{\frac34}}-1}{x}}{\left(1-{\color{blue}{2}}\sin^2{x}\right)^{\color{blue}{1}}} \,\right]dx 
\end{align} 
$$

Define the function:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
f(\color{red}{\mu},\color{red}{\nu}) &= \frac{1}{2}\,\text{B}\left(\color{red}{\mu},\color{red}{\nu}\right)\, {_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\color{red}{\mu};\frac94;2}\right)} \quad\color{blue}{\left\{{\small\varrho=1,\,k^2=2,\,\mu+\nu=\frac94}\right\}} \\[2mm] 
\implies &\boxed{\quad \color{red}{I=f\left(\frac54,\frac44\right)-f\left(\frac44,\frac54\right)+f\left(\frac34,\frac64\right)-f\left(\frac64,\frac34\right)} \quad} 
\end{align} 
$$
Which can be simplified into many forms, for example:
$$ 
\begin{align} I 
&= \frac12\,\text{B}\left({\small\frac54,\frac44}\right) {_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\frac54;\frac94;2}\right)} -\frac12\,\text{B}\left({\small\frac44,\frac54}\right) {_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\frac44;\frac94;2}\right)} \\[1mm] 
&+ \frac12\,\text{B}\left({\small\frac34,\frac64}\right) {_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\frac34;\frac94;2}\right)} -\frac12\,\text{B}\left({\small\frac64,\frac34}\right) {_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\frac64;\frac94;2}\right)} \\[4mm] 
&= \frac25 \,{_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\color{red}{\frac54};\frac94;2}\right)} -\frac25 \,{_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\color{red}{\frac44};\frac94;2}\right)} \\[1mm] 
&+ \frac25\sqrt{\small\frac{2}{\pi}}\,\Gamma^2{\small\left(\frac34\right)} \,{_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\color{red}{\small\frac34};\frac94;2}\right)} -\frac25\sqrt{\small\frac{2}{\pi}}\,\Gamma^2{\small\left(\frac34\right)} \,{_{\small2}}F{_{\small1}}{\left({1,\small\color{red}{\frac64};\frac94;2}\right)} \\[4mm] 
&\color{red}{\approx 0.5419534966847387 \dots} 
\end{align} 
$$

Another way ,using Mellin Transform with Inverse Mellin transform:
$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec (x)}+\sqrt{\csc (x)}} \, dx=\\\underset{A\to 1}{\text{lim}}\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \mathcal{M}_A\left[\frac{1}{A \sqrt{\sec
   (x)}+\sqrt{\csc (x)}}\right](s) \, dx\right](A)=\\\underset{A\to 1}{\text{lim}}\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{\pi  \csc (\pi  s) \left(\frac{\sqrt{\sec
   (x)}}{\sqrt{\csc (x)}}\right)^{-s}}{\sqrt{\csc (x)}} \, dx\right](A)=\\\underset{A\to 1}{\text{lim}}\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{2 \pi  \csc (\pi  s) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2+s}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right](A)=\\\underset{A\to 1}{\text{lim}}\frac{G_{5,5}^{5,5}\left(A,\frac{1}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \\
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\pi ^3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}=\frac{G_{5,5}^{5,5}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \\
 0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{\pi ^3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}=\\\frac{32 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \pi ^{3/2} \left(5 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)+14 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)+6 \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{1}{2};-1\right)-9\right)+12 \sqrt[4]{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+(3+3 i) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2
   \left((-16+16 i) \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)+\sqrt{4+3 \sqrt{2}} \left(-(2-4 i) \log \left(3+2 \sqrt{2}-2 \sqrt{4+3 \sqrt{2}}\right)+(-4+4 i) \tan ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{4+3
   \sqrt{2}}\right)+\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{21} \sqrt{12+11 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)}{48 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}$
where: $G_{5,5}^{5,5}$ is MeijerG function.
Update:
If we use more simplify:
$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec (x)}+\sqrt{\csc (x)}} \, dx=\frac{5 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)}{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}+\frac{14 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)}{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}+\frac{2 \sqrt{2}
   \pi ^{3/2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{1}{2};-1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}-2+\frac{3 \pi }{16 \sqrt[4]{2}}-\frac{3 \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt[4]{2}}+\frac{\csc ^{-1}\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)}{8
   \sqrt[4]{2}}+\frac{\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{2}}-\frac{3 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}$
Mathematica code:
NIntegrate[1/(Sqrt[Sec[x]] + Sqrt[Csc[x]]), {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 200] - 
1/96 (9 2^(3/4) \[Pi] + 
6 (-32 - 6 2^(3/4) ArcCot[2^(1/4)] + 8 2^(3/4) ArcCoth[2^(1/4)] + 
   2^(3/4) ArcCsc[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]) + (
32 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(
 3/2) (-9 + 5 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1, 1/4, -1] + 
   14 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, 1/4, -1] + 
   6 Hypergeometric2F1[3/4, 1, 1/2, -1]))/Gamma[1/4]^2);

(* 0.*10^-201 *)


Could you simplify your final answer?

@DylanLevine Mathematica can't better simplify.

@MariuszIwaniuk. Mathematica can't better simplify. but what about you ? Cheers :-)

@DylanLevine .See my update. :)

I was ready to bet that you will be coming with something simpler. Thanks
